# Kotlin remove button's background tint

Tags: android, button, background

I am trying to set a custom background behaviour for my button in Android Studio project, but `backgroundTint` color keeps interfering with my custom drawable resource.

When I set `backgroundTint` to the new color, I still can't get `background` working correctly. It's just the tint color.

For some reason, if I don't set my custom `backgroundTint` color, it just copies `colorPrimary`.

I also have `android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_state"` in my `xml` file and I've tried setting the background color programmatically `btnSelectFile.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_button_state)`, although, I'd like to avoid setting it programmatically since I believe it the solution must be much easier.

My `rounded_button_state.xml` drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_dark_teal_rounded_corners"
            android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_bluish_rounded_corners"
            android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

My `background_dark_teal_rounded_corners.xml` drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="125">
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_teal"/>
            <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

My `background_bluish_rounded_corners.xml` drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:alpha="125">
<shape  android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/bluish_grey"/>
    <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

My main_activity.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFileName"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSelectFile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_state"
            android:text="@string/tvSelectFile" />


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In my `values/themes.xml` I have:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
```

My full `values/themes.xml` file looks like this:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.TestFragmentUpdate" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
<!--        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>-->
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
<!--        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>-->
<!--        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>-->
<!--        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>-->
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

My second file `night/themes.xml` in `themes` folder looks like this:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.TestFragmentUpdate" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/bluish_grey</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/dark_teal</item>
<!--        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>-->
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
<!--        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>-->
<!--        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>-->
<!--        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>-->
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is when I set a `backgroundTint` to my own custom color:

[image]

And that's when I delete my custom `backgroundTint` color and the primary one is used:

[image]

Comment: Because you are using material button and it uses background for image and stuff and for applying color you need to set background tint for that!

Comment: What happens if you set the tint to #FFFFFFFF?

Comment: Hi @ChiragBargoojar, how can I change it to the normal button?

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04, if I set it to the color you mentioned, it just becomes the same color as a fragment's background color so it's barely visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume you are using a normal `Button` and then you set the `style`, don't do it:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
```

Or maybe you are using a `MaterialButton`.

Anyway, the documentation says to don't change the background:

> All attributes from MaterialButton are supported. Do not use the
> android:background attribute. MaterialButton manages its own
> background drawable, and setting a new background means MaterialButton
> can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it introduces will
> function properly. If the default background is changed,
> MaterialButton cannot guarantee well-defined behavior.

If you want to use a custom background, as I see you have a `drawable` for this purpose, use just a normal `Button`.

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/myBackground"/>
```

Edit:

Your theme style it's making the button to be a `MaterialButton` so now you can do two things:

-> You can change the full theme to a normal one:

```
<style name="Theme.TestFragmentUpdate" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

This will change the full theme of your app.

-> You can change just the button theme

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="Theme.TestFragmentUpdate" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/bluish_grey</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/dark_teal</item>
            <item name="buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Button</item>
    
    <!--        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>-->
            <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <!--        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>-->
    <!--        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>-->
    <!--        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>-->
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Also, I think it could work that you set this concret style (The default Style) to the button and after just set the background you need so you don't modify the full theme:

```
<Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
       android:background="@drawable/myBackground"/>
```

Comment: Hi Bogdan Android and thanks a lot for your comment! Is there any way I can change it to the normal button? I updated my answer with how I set my button.

Comment: Hi there, do you have it in XML like <Button> or like <MaterialButton>?

Comment: I've just added an update to my answer. :) But it's <Button>.

Comment: Can you add please your full styles.xml ?

Comment: Just removed ```app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFFFF"``` because it was for testing purposes.

Comment: And one more thing, also post the code of your drawable (the one you use as background)

Comment: I don't really have ```styles.xml``` but I do have themes. That's strange. I can add them for you to see. :)

Comment: Thank you, everything helps to see where the button get this style from.

Comment: Added! Please, see an updated answer. Thank you so much @BogdanAndroid! :)

Comment: Sorry @BogdanAndroid, haven't noticed earlier. Added drawables as well!

Comment: Don't worry :) I am writing the answer now, give me a moment

Comment: Done, please, check my last eddit.

Comment: thank you so much! It finally worked when I changed the full theme to a normal one! Thank you!